In Magento 2, I used a renderer, but after using the renderer, the text box is not editable
$this->addColumn(
        'customer_price',
        [
            'header' => __('Customer Price'),
            'type' => 'input',
            'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
            'index' => 'customer_price',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-customer-price',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-customer-price',
            'renderer' => \Bliss\PricePerCustomer\Block\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product\Grid\Column\Renderer\CustomerPriceRenderer::class,
        ]
    );


the value you return from renderer do it like this ---------------> return '';

okay but after i have post data then this price not passed

share your Renderer file code

public function render(DataObject $row)
{
$productId = $row->getId();
$collection = $this->_customerPriceCollFactory->create();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId);
    $customerPrice = '';
    foreach ($collection as $item) {
        $customerPrice = $item->getCustomerPrice();
    }
    return '<input type="text" value="' . $customerPrice . '" />'; 
}


Modify the Grid Preparation:-
$this->addColumn(
            'customer_special_price',
            [
                'header' => __('Customer Special Price'),
                'type' => 'price', // Change to 'price' type
                'currency_code' => $store->getBaseCurrency()->getCode(),
                'index' => 'customer_special_price',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-customer-special-price',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-customer-special-price',
                'renderer' => '\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Input'
                // Explicitly set input renderer
            ]
        );

